# Why Plot[] fails to generate images of such simple exponential functions?

Tags: plotting, functions

Recently I am trying to plot images of the exponential functions like $1.25\times (-0.4)^k +13.75\times 1.2^k $ and $-0.3125\times (-0.4)^k +10.3125\times 1.2^k $ in the range of $0\leq k \leq 8$. At the beginning, I thought it was easy for Plot[] to draw images of such functions. But to my surprise, no matter how hard I try, Plot[] keeps failing to do so, returning an empty plot like below every time:

[image]

The code I use is below and I believe I have followed the correct syntax to the letter. The coding is not the reason why Plot[] does not work.

```
f = 1.25 (-0.4)^k + 13.75 1.2^k;
Plot[f, {k, 0, 8}]
```

So my questions are:

1. Why Plot[] fails to draw the image of such simple exponential functions?

2.Is there any good way to generate the plot of such functions in a continuous manner by one step? I have tried to generate a table first and then employ the ListLinePlot[], which obviously works. But I am a little disappointed that it should cost MMA 2 steps to plot such a simple image! Any one-step solution is welcome.

Plots by Table[] and ListLinePlot[] is attached below. I post it here to show the range of the function in  $0\leq k \leq 8$ is totally normal. It is not because the functional range is too small or too big that leads to the failure of Plot[].

[image]

Comment: (-0.4)^k is a Complex Values function.

Comment: Plot the real part of your function value with [`Re`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Re.html).

Comment: The problem is that your function is complex valued. Try e.g.: `(-0.4)^0.1`. You may e.g. use `ReIm`.

Comment: My thanks go to all of you @cvgmt @rowsi @Daniel Huber to help me come to realize that exponential function with negative base defined on a continuous real range is complex valued so that Plot[] cannot generate the image on a real plane. That’ s why Plot[] does not work in this case.

Moreover, actually my model is defined on non-negative integers, such definition has guaranteed the functional value is always real. That’s why employing `ListLinePlot[Table[f,{k,0,8}]]` can successfully plot the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This defines a complex-valued function.Take a look at

```
f = 1.25 (-0.4)^k + 13.75 *1.2^k;Plot[{Re[f], Im[f]}, {k, 0, 8}]
```

[image]

Comment: It should be noticed that `Limit[Rationalize[Im[1.25 (-0.4)^k + 13.75 *1.2^k],0], k -> Infinity]` results in `0`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me come to realize that exponential function with negative base defined on a continuous real range is complex valued so that Plot[] cannot generate the image on a real plane. That’ s why Plot[] does not work in this case. Moreover, actually my model is defined on non-negative integers, such definition has guaranteed the functional value is always real. That’s why employing ListLinePlot[Table[f,{k,0,8}]] can successfully plot the image.